# Android BLE - how to save battery lfie

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

my client wants an application which essentially uses all these all the time i.e. in a background service:
- network/wifi
- location service
- BLE scanning

Which means this has a big effect on the battery life. According to my measures it can lower your battery more than 10% per hour this way.

What would be the best way to lower energy consumption, and which one of the three services would consume the most power? The location service only gets updated if the user location changes significantly (can happen while travelling), and there is constant client-server communication going on in the background.

And the whole idea is that BLE is constantly scanning. What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to be constantly scanning? A better solution would be to scan for short time intervals (for example 2 seconds) every 5, 10, 20 or more seconds. You get the idea.

I highly doubt that the available devices would change faster than this and if they do, you most likely won't be able to connect to them.